# How to use flex-grow?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, bootstrap-4

In the doc and in the issues of Bootstrap v4 [(here)](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/), I can't see any plan on supporting `flex-grow`, something with a syntax like this for example:

```
<div class="d-flex">
      <div  class="flex-grow">
        I use all the space left
      </div>
      <div>
        I am a small text on the right
      </div>
</div>
```

Here a sample of the layout I'd like to create:

[image]

The export button is always on the right, and the navigation button takes all the space left and therefore looks clean.

Is it possible to build such a layout already? Maybe it is not advised? Of course, there are workarounds using CSS, but I am looking for a clean solution, ideally using Bootstrap class names only to guarantee consistency.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

use `.col` for a simple `flex-grow: 1;`. It's described here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      I use all the space left
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm col-sm-auto">
      I am a small text on the right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well, and should be the accepted answer. It will also work with `row>col` instead of `d-flex>col` http://www.codeply.com/go/rcJBwXRjSN

Comment: Does it works with vertical layout ? For example when the top menu should always appear, and the content should take all the vertical space left ?

Comment: @EricBurel use breakpoint grid classes on the non `.col` column, and put everything in `.row` and `.container`. It's all referenced in the link I provided. Updated my answer.

Comment: This solution isn't atomic enough. It adds much more than just `flex-grow`, padding for starters. I'd say it makes more sense to find a utility library in the spirit of Bootstrap that does supply such an atomic utility class.

Answer (score 46):

For anyone comming here from a google search (like me).

Since Bootstrap v 4.1 there are `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` utilities, as the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) says you can use them like this:

```
.flex-{grow|shrink}-0
.flex-{grow|shrink}-1
.flex-sm-{grow|shrink}-0
.flex-sm-{grow|shrink}-1
```

Here is a little example

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 text-white justify-content-center bg-danger">
    Grow 1
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-0 text-white justify-content-center bg-success">
    Grow 0
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 text-white justify-content-center bg-danger">
    Grow 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but they are missing utilities to add different numbers to that grow parameter (like flex-grow-sm-2/3/4/5 etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I created a class for this, I checked the Bootstrap docs and found nothing about it.

```
.flex-2 { flex-grow: 2 }
```

`col-auto` takes the remaining space but if you have more than one row, so space won't be distributed equally. That's why `flex-grow` does the trick.